# Entire shiny app turns white after trying to formatstyle a data table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

For some reason, trying to add a formatStyle to my data table object in this particular example results in the entire app not working. There are no error messages, just that all the outputs display nothing. The only things I see are the buttons and the user inputs.

I have tried two different methods of accomplishing what I want. Both ways result in no error messages and the white output.

I use a function to create the data table within the app.

```r
create_platform_table <- function(count_platform, row_name) {

   background <- "value == 'No Platform' ? '#5EDD6B' : value != 'else' ? '#FFBF33' : ''"
   class(background) <- "JS_EVAL"

   my_vals <- as.character(unique(count_platform()$PLATFORM))
   my_colors <- ifelse(my_vals == 'No platform', 'red', 'blue')

   data <- count_platform[,c('PLATFORM', 'Population')]

   dat <- datatable(data, selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell'),
                    options = list(
                      rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '15px')}")),
                    callback = JS(gsub("\n", "", paste0("table.on('click.dt', 'td', function() {
                                                        var row_=table.cell(this).index().row;
                                                        var col=table.cell(this).index().column;
                                                        var rnd= Math.random();
                                                        var data = [row_, col, rnd];
                                                        Shiny.onInputChange(", row_name, ",data );
 });"))) ) %>%
     formatStyle('PLATFORM', target = 'row', 
                 backgroundColor = styleEqual(my_vals, my_colors))

   return(dat)

}
```

The above runs fine without the %>% formatStyle part of the code.

This has me stumped because I have used formatStyle just fine on another data table. And the weirdest thing is that trying to use formatStyle here stops the other outputs that have nothing to do with the data table output I'm trying to make.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a weird bug?

Comment: What is `count_platform` ? Why the parentheses here: `count_platform()` ?

Comment: It's an aggregate dataframe grouped by platform. The count_platform() is just something I forgot to turn into a variable for function but doesn't make much of a difference here. It's a reactive variable.

Comment: I really don't see why this doesn't work. Could you provide a reproducible code, with the dataframe ?

Comment: I can't, unfortunately - classified data. Since there is no error, I'm at a loss on what I can change.

Comment: Could you provide just a sample of the data ? You can also modify the data values.

Comment: I would have to ask someone to be safe, but even then, the answer is probably no unless I modify the data entirely to gibberish which takes up a lot of time.